# liferay portlet can't get input field value

Tags: java, input, liferay, portlet

I can't figure out why i can't get an input value from a jsp. I'm using for cycle to make several input fiels for "choices", but when i'm trying to get values from a mvcportlet, it get nothing.

```
<aui:form action="<%=addPollURL%>">
    <aui:fieldset>
        <%
            int optionCount = Integer.parseInt(optionCountS);
            for (int i = 0; i < optionCount; i++) {
        %>
        <aui:input label="<%=Integer.toString(i + 1)%>" name="choice<%=i%>"
            type="text" />
        <%
            }
        %>
        <aui:button-row>
            <aui:button value="Add poll" type="submit" />
        </aui:button-row>
    </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

Here goes mvcportlet method

```
List<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(actualChoiceCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.err
                    .println("another choice"
                            + ParamUtil
                                    .getString(
                                            actionRequest,
                                            ("choice" + i)));
            choices.add(new String(ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,
                    ("choice" + i))));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its really weird... but some ideas or tests

1. Is AddPollUrl an Action URL with named action and so your action is executed in your generic portlet?
2. Are you sure text fields are populated with values in the UI (there is no no explicit value in tag)? ParamUtil output would be the same without value that with a blank value
3. Try without type=text and write it as a single line (input tags)
4. Try aui:submit instead of aui:button type submit
5. Try adding an id to form or fields (Ive seen some problems with repeated forms if they dont have namespace)
6. Why new String(ParamUtil...)?

the most important... whats the output of your System.outs?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because your input field has no value. Or at least it seems so.
You should modify the input to have the value parameter set to "choiceX" like:

```
<aui:input label="<%=Integer.toString(i + 1)%>" name="choice<%=i%>"
        type="text" value="choice<%=i%>" />
```

Then you'll find it in actionRequest, like Jonny said:

```
request.getParameter("choice"+i);
```

This will return you the **value** of the input field, searching by it's name. So you can have your choice in the processAction method.

Regards !

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
actionRequest.getParameter("choice" + i);
```

That's not the standard way of getting POST params from the request.